# How to set custom font to a html loaded with a WebView in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to load a custom font into a webview. I know there are several solutions but non worked for me.

I am loading the data into the webview with this:

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", setHTML(it), "text/html", "utf-8", null)



private fun setHTML(text: String): String {
    return "<html><style>" +
            "@font-face {" +
            "font-family: 'Montserrat';" +
            "src: url('fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf);" +
            "}" +
            "body {" +
            "padding:0px;"+
            "margin:0px;"+
            "font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !important;" +
            "}" +
            "a {" +
            "text-decoration:none;" +
            "}" +
            "code {" +
            "font-family: Courier, Helvetica !important;" +
            "}" +
            "</style><body>${text}ffff</body></html>"
}
```

And my text is i.e `<b> test </b>`

Here are my fonts which I'd like to use:

[image]

Anybody got an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
String text = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: MyFont;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/font/Montserrat-Regular.ttf\")}body {font-family: MyFont;font-size: medium;text-align: justify;}</style></head><body>";
String pas = "</body></html>";
String myHtmlString = text+ YourTxext + pas;
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,myHtmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```